# Use part of regexp result set to make match

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Is it posible to use any sub result from a regexp to make up the entire regexp, consider this snippet:

```
var ret = "{hello} {world}";
ret = ret.replace(/(^|[^{}])(\{|\})([^{}]|$)/g, '$1$2$2$3');
ret; // {{hello}} {{world}}
```

But when I put `}{` together the above regexp will fail, which also makes sense cause I'm testing against none of `}{` or beginning of string and then one of `{}` and then again none of `{}` or end of string:

```
var ret = "{hello}{world}";
ret = ret.replace(/(^|[^{}])(\{|\})([^{}]|$)/g, '$1$2$2$3');
ret; // {{hello}{world}}
```

Is it posible to use the frist result set to make the second and then again make the third:

```
/(^|[^{}])($1)([^{}]|$)/g, '$1$2$2$3'
//         $1 - or something similarly
```

I'm avare of that I can use multiply `·replace` method calls but it would be cool just to have one.

Thanks

---

Don't consider the readability of the code.

Comment: What exactly is the objective of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this one regexp work for you?

```
ret.replace(/[{]+(.*?)[}]+/g, '{{$1}}')
```

p.s.: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: But I changed it to only replace `{`x1 and x2  not xN+1: `ret.replace(/[{]{1,2}(.*?)[}]{1,2}/g, '{{$1}}');`

Comment: This doesn't answer the essence of my question, but gives me a solution to my question :) I was just stupid not to see this. Looking me blind on trying to figure out what came before in the regex... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Backreferences, e.g. `\1` sounds like what you're looking for (if I understood your question correctly).

Comment: This got one step closer to finding the answer :)